# Alert Dialog preparation

Tags: android, alert, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

[image: Alret Widdow]

Hi,

I need some help to remove the dark color that appears on the Alerts Dialog box edge but at the same time i need the dim background activity as well.

If you see the image properly you will find two colors 
1-appears around the Alert Dialog(which i need  to remove).
2-other is the dim background(which is required to be there) of background activity.

***I have already removed the border r of custum_dialog layout which i have used for alert dialog

My code for Alert-dialog  window is as below

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        final View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(
                R.layout.custum_dialog, null);

        TextView tv=(TextView) deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.errormsg);
        tv.setText(getErrMsg());
        //tv.setText("jsfj ajsd jkasd j juasdf jbasd u uasd juasd ");
        final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create();
        deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
        deleteDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
       // deleteDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        //deleteDialog.setCustomTitle(tv);
        deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.okbtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //your business logic 
                deleteDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


        deleteDialog.show();
     // Remove padding from parent
```

Comment: Can you post "custum_dialog.xml"?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create `Custom Dialog Theme` and set to your `Dialog` like below on `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now, set this theme to your `Dialog` like below:

```
Dialog main_dialog = new Dialog(Splash.this,R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

And customized this theme parameter as per your requirement. thnx